# A question about map$\phi$ such that $\inf\{\phi(x)+\phi(y):d(x,y)\ge\gamma\} = \mu(\gamma)>0 \text{ for all } \gamma >0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $(X, d)$ be a complete metric space and let $\phi: X \to [0, \infty)$ be a map(not necessarily continuous). Suppose:$$\inf\{\phi(x)+\phi(y):d(x,y)\ge\gamma\} = \mu(\gamma)>0 \text{ for all } \gamma >0$$Show that each sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$, for which $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\phi(x_n)}=0$ converge to one and only one point $u \in X$.

This is an exercise on page 10 of *Fixed point theory and applications*, Ravi Agarwal et al.I don't know where to start. What makes maps satisfy $\inf\{\phi(x)+\phi(y):d(x,y)\ge\gamma\} = \mu(\gamma)>0$, for all $ \gamma >0$ interesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\sigma=\langle x_k:k\in\omega\rangle$ is a sequence in $X$ such that $\langle\varphi(x_k):k\in\omega\rangle\to 0$; I’ll show that $\sigma$ is $d$-Cauchy and hence convergent. Let $\epsilon>0$; there is an $m_\epsilon\in\omega$ such that $\varphi(x_k)<\frac12\mu(\epsilon)$ whenever $k\ge m_\epsilon$, and hence $\varphi(x_k)+\varphi(x_n)<\mu(\epsilon)$ whenever $k,n\ge m_\epsilon$. But

$$\mu(\epsilon)=\inf\{\varphi(x)+\varphi(y):d(x,y)\ge\epsilon\}\;,$$

so $d(x_k,x_n)<\epsilon$ whenever $k,n\ge m_\epsilon$, and $\sigma$ is $d$-Cauchy. $\langle X,d\rangle$ is complete, so $\sigma$ converges to some $x\in X$, which is of course unique.